# Aggregate over column arrays in DataFrame in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

Let's say I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
[Row(user='bob', values=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2]),
Row(user='bob', values=[0.1, 0.3, 0.6]),
Row(user='bob', values=[0.8, 0.1, 0.1])]
```

I would like to `groupBy` `user` and do something like `avg(values)` where the average is taken over each index of the array `values` like this:

```
[Row(user='bob', avgerages=[0.466667, 0.233333, 0.3])]
```

How can I do this in PySpark?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can expand array and compute average for each index.

**Python**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, avg, col

n = len(df.select("values").first()[0])

df.groupBy("user").agg(
    array(*[avg(col("values")[i]) for i in range(n)]).alias("averages")
)
```

**Scala**

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.functions.{avg, size}

val df = Seq(
  ("bob", Seq(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)),
  ("bob", Seq(0.1, 0.3, 0.6))
).toDF("user", "values")

val n = df.select(size($"values")).as[Int].first
val values = (0 to n).map(i => $"values"(i))

df.select($"user" +: values: _*).groupBy($"user").avg()
```

Comment: What does the * do in this case? Also, is there a way like in Pandas where I could pass each group to a user-defined function and do the operation in there? Thanks.

Comment: `*` is a standard Python argument unpacking. No, Python doesn't support UDAFs. You can use RDDs directly or define JVM one.

Comment: Thanks! I think RDD makes sense here.

Comment: If you want to give RDD a try you can use a subset (`compute_stats` without collect) of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36361546/1560062).

Comment: @Gevorg Here you are. You may also find interesting http://stackoverflow.com/q/41731865/1560062

Comment: @zero323 would it be possible to use agg() and have the end result in a single column (of array type containing the averages)?

Comment: @Gevorg Yup, just wrap it with `o.a.s.sql.functions.array`.

Comment: `n = len(df.select("values").first()[0])` how could this be done where the length is variable?

Comment: @con `n = len(df.select(max("values").)first()[0])`?  Or maybe `df.select("user", posexplode("values")).groupBy("user", "pos").avg()`?

Comment: My aim is to use aggregated data in different columns, for which I am using:
`AggregateDF = TimeWindowDF.groupBy('col1','col2').agg(
    f.array(*[f.avg(f.col("value.count").getItem(0))]).alias("avg_count"),
    f.array(*[f.avg(f.col("value.occ").getItem(0))]).alias("avg_occ"),
    f.array(*[f.avg(f.col("value.speed").getItem(0))]).alias("avg_speed"))`
But the columns I am having are of datatype array<double>, however I want them to be in type double. How that can be achieved?