# PySpark: how to aggregate over column arrays with variable width?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am attempting to aggregate and create an array of means thus (this is a Minimal Working Example):

```
n = len(allele_freq_total.select("alleleFrequencies").first()[0])

allele_freq_by_site = allele_freq_total.groupBy("contigName", "start", "end", "referenceAllele").agg(
  array(*[mean(col("alleleFrequencies")[i]) for i in range(n)]).alias("mean_alleleFrequencies")
```

using a solution that I got from

[Aggregate over column arrays in DataFrame in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982231/aggregate-over-column-arrays-in-dataframe-in-pyspark)

but the problem is that `n` is  variable, how do I alter

`array(*[mean(col("alleleFrequencies")[i]) for i in range(n)])`

so that it takes variable length into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

With arrays of unequal size in the different groups (for you, a group is `("contigName", "start", "end", "referenceAllele")`, which I'll simply rename to `group`), you could consider exploding the array column (the `alleleFrequencies`), with introduction of the position the values had within the arrays. That will give you an additional column you can use in grouping to compute the average you had in mind. At this point you might actually have enough for further computations (see `df3.show()` below).

If you really must have it back into an array, that's harder and I haven't an idea. One must keep track of the order, and I believe that's easy with a map (a dictionary, if you like). To do so, I use the aggregation function `collect_list` on two columns. While `collect_list` isn't deterministic (you don't know the order in which values will be returned in the list, because rows are shuffled), the aggregation over both arrays will preserve their order, as the rows get shuffled in their entirety (see `df4.show()`, below). From there, you can create a mapping of the position to the average with `map_from_arrays`.

Example:

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import mean, col, posexplode, collect_list, map_from_arrays
>>> 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([
...     ("A", [0, 1, 2]),
...     ("A", [0, 3, 6]),
...     ("B", [1, 2, 4, 5]),
...     ("B", [1, 2, 6, 1])],
...     schema=("group", "values"))
>>> df2 = df.select(df.group, posexplode(df.values))  # adds the "pos" and "col" columns
>>> df3 = (df2
...        .groupBy("group", "pos")
...        .agg(mean(col("col")).alias("avg_of_positions"))
...        )
>>> df4 = (df3
...        .groupBy("group")
...        .agg(
...          collect_list("pos").alias("pos"),
...          collect_list("avg_of_positions").alias("avgs")
...          )
...        )
>>> df5 = df4.select(
...     "group",
...     map_from_arrays(col("pos"), col("avgs")).alias("positional_averages")
... )
>>> df5.show(truncate=False)
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 4) / 4]
+-----+----------------------------------------+                                
|group|positional_averages                     |
+-----+----------------------------------------+
|B    |[0 -> 1.0, 1 -> 2.0, 3 -> 3.0, 2 -> 5.0]|
|A    |[0 -> 0.0, 1 -> 2.0, 2 -> 4.0]          |
+-----+----------------------------------------+
```