# MatchError while accessing vector column in Spark 2.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to create a LDA model on a JSON file.

Creating a spark context with the JSON file :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("my-spark-app")
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "config-value")
  .getOrCreate()

 val df = spark.read.json("dbfs:/mnt/JSON6/JSON/sampleDoc.txt")
```

Displaying the `df` should show the `DataFrame`

```
display(df)
```

Tokenize the text

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer

// Set params for RegexTokenizer
val tokenizer = new RegexTokenizer()
                .setPattern("[\\W_]+")
                .setMinTokenLength(4) // Filter away tokens with length < 4
                .setInputCol("text")
                .setOutputCol("tokens")

// Tokenize document
val tokenized_df = tokenizer.transform(df)
```

This should be displaying the `tokenized_df`

```
display(tokenized_df)
```

Get the `stopwords`

```
%sh wget http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/resources/linguistic_utils/stop_words > -O /tmp/stopwords
```

Optional: copying the stopwords to the tmp folder

```
%fs cp file:/tmp/stopwords dbfs:/tmp/stopwords
```

Collecting all the `stopwords`

```
val stopwords = sc.textFile("/tmp/stopwords").collect()
```

Filtering out the `stopwords`

```
 import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover

 // Set params for StopWordsRemover
 val remover = new StopWordsRemover()
                   .setStopWords(stopwords) // This parameter is optional
                   .setInputCol("tokens")
                   .setOutputCol("filtered")

 // Create new DF with Stopwords removed
 val filtered_df = remover.transform(tokenized_df)
```

Displaying the filtered `df` should verify the `stopwords` got removed

```
 display(filtered_df)
```

Vectorizing the frequency of occurrence of words

```
 import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
 import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
 import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer

 // Set params for CountVectorizer
 val vectorizer = new CountVectorizer()
               .setInputCol("filtered")
               .setOutputCol("features")
               .fit(filtered_df)
```

Verify the `vectorizer`

```
 vectorizer.transform(filtered_df)
           .select("id", "text","features","filtered").show()
```

After this I am seeing an issue in fitting this `vectorizer` in LDA. The issue which I believe is `CountVectorizer` is giving sparse vector but LDA requires dense vector. Still trying to figure out the issue.

Here is the exception where map is not able to convert.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
val ldaDF = countVectors.map { 
             case Row(id: String, countVector: Vector) => (id, countVector) 
            }
display(ldaDF)
```

Exception :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4083.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4083.0 (TID 15331, 10.209.240.17): scala.MatchError: [0,(1252,[13,17,18,20,30,37,45,50,51,53,63,64,96,101,108,125,174,189,214,221,224,227,238,268,291,309,328,357,362,437,441,455,492,493,511,528,561,613,619,674,764,823,839,980,1098,1143],[1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
```

There is a working sample for LDA which is not throwing any issue

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{DistributedLDAModel, LDA}

val a = Vectors.dense(Array(1.0,2.0,3.0))
val b = Vectors.dense(Array(3.0,4.0,5.0))
val df = Seq((1L,a),(2L,b),(2L,a)).toDF

val ldaDF = df.map { case Row(id: Long, countVector: Vector) => (id, countVector) } 

val model = new LDA().setK(3).run(ldaDF.javaRDD)
display(df)
```

The only difference is in the second snippet we are having a dense matrix.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has nothing to do with sparsity. Since Spark 2.0.0 ML `Transformers` no longer generate `o.a.s.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT` but `o.a.s.ml.linalg.VectorUDT` and are mapped locally to subclasses of `o.a.s.ml.linalg.Vector`. These are not compatible with old MLLib API which is moving towards deprecation in Spark 2.0.0.

You can convert between to "old" using `Vectors.fromML`:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors => OldVectors}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vectors => NewVectors}

OldVectors.fromML(NewVectors.dense(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
OldVectors.fromML(NewVectors.sparse(5, Seq(0 -> 1.0, 2 -> 2.0, 4 -> 3.0)))
```

but it make more sense to use `ML` implementation of LDA if you already use ML transformers.

For convenience you can use implicit conversions:

```
import scala.languageFeature.implicitConversions

object VectorConversions {
  import org.apache.spark.mllib.{linalg => mllib}
  import org.apache.spark.ml.{linalg => ml}

  implicit def toNewVector(v: mllib.Vector) = v.asML
  implicit def toOldVector(v: ml.Vector) = mllib.Vectors.fromML(v)
}
```

Comment: Also the error messages related to this type mismatch are very confusing. For instance `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(VecFunction)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires vector type, however, 'VecFunction' is of vector type.;` 

Note how both argument and expected input are said to be vector type.

Comment: should that not be `org.apache.spark.mllib.*linalg*.Vectors.fromML` ?  Oh and btw that was helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

I changed:

```
val ldaDF = countVectors.map { 
             case Row(id: String, countVector: Vector) => (id, countVector) 
            }
```

to:

```
val ldaDF = countVectors.map { case Row(docId: String, features: MLVector) => 
                               (docId.toLong, Vectors.fromML(features)) }
```

And it worked like a charm! It is aligned with what @zero323 has written.

List of imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{CountVectorizer, RegexTokenizer, StopWordsRemover}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector => MLVector}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{LDA, OnlineLDAOptimizer}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
```

Answer (score -6):

Solution is very simple guys.. find below

```
//import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
```