# How to convert Spark DataFrame column of sparse vectors to a column of dense vectors?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I used the following code:

```
df.withColumn("dense_vector", $"sparse_vector".toDense)
```

but it gives an error.

I am new to Spark, so this might be obvious and there may be obvious errors in my code line. Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contexts which require operation like this are relatively rare in Spark. With one or two exception Spark API expects common `Vector` class not specific implementation (`SparseVector`, `DenseVector`). This is also true in case of distributed structures from `o.a.s.mllib.linalg.distributed`

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

val df = Seq[(Long, Vector)](
  (1L, Vectors.dense(1, 2, 3)), (2L, Vectors.sparse(3, Array(1), Array(3)))
).toDF("id", "v")

new RowMatrix(df.select("v")
  .map(_.getAs[Vector]("v")))
  .columnSimilarities(0.9)
  .entries
  .first
// apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.MatrixEntry = MatrixEntry(0,2,1.0)
```

Nevertheless you could use an UDF like this:

```scala
val asDense = udf((v: Vector) => v.toDense)

df.withColumn("vd", asDense($"v")).show
// +---+-------------+-------------+
// | id|            v|           vd|
// +---+-------------+-------------+
// |  1|[1.0,2.0,3.0]|[1.0,2.0,3.0]|
// |  2|(3,[1],[3.0])|[0.0,3.0,0.0]|
// +---+-------------+-------------+
```

Just keep in mind that since version 2.0 Spark provides two different and compatible `Vector` types:

- `o.a.s.ml.linalg.Vector`
- `o.a.s.mllib.linalg.Vector`

each with corresponding SQL UDT. See [MatchError while accessing vector column in Spark 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38818879/1560062)