# How to cast a variable of type ML sparse vector type to MLlib sparse vector type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

When I try to create the labelled points from output of Vector Transformer, I am facing the following problem:

```
  val realout = output.select("label","features").rdd.map(row => LabeledPoint
   row.getAs[Double]("label"),
row.getAs[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector]("features")
))
```

The error I am getting is:

```
enter [error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 13, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
[error]     at DataCleaning$$anonfun$1.apply(DataCleaning.scala:107
[error]     at DataCleaning$$anonfun$1.apply(DataCleaning.scala:105)
[error] 
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
[error]
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462
[error]
atorg.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:213)
```

I checked the solution provided in the link[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818879/matcherror-while-accessing-vector-column-in-spark-2-0) which explain conversion of a vector in spark 2.0.0, but facing a compilation error as mentioned below,

```
object linalg is not a member of package org.apache.spark.ml
```

Kindly Help . Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

There is a static method in `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector` to convert new linalg type to `spark.mllib` type called `fromML`. It can be use to convert ML sparse vector to MLlib Sparse Vector.  Remember that it only copies references.

You can use it as follows:

```
   val realout : RDD[LabeledPoint] = features1.rdd.map(row => LabeledPoint(row.getAs[Double]("label"), 
  SparseVector.fromML(row.getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector]("features"))))
```

Refer Spark Documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/SparseVector.html

P.S. -: This documentation direct to Java but my example code is in Scala. But, it has no problem because Scala is compatible with Java. That's mean you can call the methods of either language from methods in the other one.

Comment: @hshihab It's okay since Scala is compatible with Java. So you can use the above mention methodology in both languages. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: The Scala docs are here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector$

Comment: @KarlHigley Thank you