# Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce

Tags: apache-spark

spark version is 2.2.0 and scala version is 2.11。When I use ml lib, error occurs : " Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce."

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

 val trainingData = dataSet
  .select(col("features"), col("label")).cache()

val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(maxIter)
  .setRegParam(regParam)
  .setElasticNetParam(0)
  .setThreshold(threshold)
  .setFitIntercept(false)

val lrModel = lr.fit(trainingData)
```

It confused me several days。Who can help me?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it as such, not completely rewrite existing one.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear you are using `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT` (the old MLlib API) while any new API (ML) requires `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector`.

You omitted the part of the code where you create `dataSet`, but you should replace:

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg._
```

imports with:

```
org.apache.spark.ml._
```

and adjust upstream code accordingly.

Related:

- [MatchError while accessing vector column in Spark 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38818879/8371915)